# Stop Iframe make requests

Tags: iframe, .net-framework-version

I have 3 modal iframes and theare autoplay from this url extension "?start=0&end=5;autoplay=1&mute=1".But after looping my app still make requests to youtube.My projects is in .Net Framework 4.5.

```
<div id="modalId">

            <a href="#" id="latest_video" class="pull-left">

                <iframe id="@modalId" class="stop-video"src="@String.Format("{0}{1}", video.VideoUrl, "?start=0&end=5;autoplay=1&mute=1")" allowfullscreen="true" style="height:210px;max-width:240.33px;background-color:black"></iframe>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: May be progressively load your videos https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593816/10634638

Comment: ok but YT.Player is this a js library.Vs intelisense dont recognise.

Comment: If you look at this section they load a script tag into header, which points to YouTube_api .js file which has YT defined: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started